# Is a 6 pin PCI-X power connector safe to use on a card that only requires 5 pins?

Tags: power-supply, pci-express, pci-x

I know that on a 6 pin PCI-X power connector the spec says pin 2 can be disconnected. It is another 12v pin like pins 1 & 3. If my graphics card only requires a 5 pin connector, is it still safe to use a 6 pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a 5 pin PCIe connector (pci-x is totally different from PCIe and is hardly used. Its PCI-extended, not PCI express)  - there's 6 and 8 pin connectors, and the middle '12v' connector is optional in 6 pin connectors - see the [pinout](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/PCI_Express_%28PCIe%29_6pin_power) for a 6 pin connector here. It should be entirely safe.

Triple 12V connections on 6 pin PCIe seems to be for compatibility with [8 pin](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/PCI_Express_%28PCIe%29_8pin_power)  power connectors, which *must* have 3 12V inputs, and is often supplied as a 6+2 pin connector. The extra 12V is ignored in that case.